GNU Radio TDOA signal processing
this is my first month using GNU Radio and SDR, and I’m trying to implement the TDOA method. I have an ExpressLRS (ELRS) transmitter on my remote, and I want to record signal samples only when my source is active and only at a specific frequency, due to the high sample rate of 20e6. However, I am stuck on the signal recording and processing step. Can someone advise me on my GNU Radio setup? Are there any mistakes or missing parts? Is there a more efficient way to implement this? Should I do something else with my signal before/after recording it? I am literally don't understand what I am trying to get from my SDR. Thank you.
I’ve tried using a bandpass filter to isolate my frequency of interest, followed by a squelch block with a gate to record signals only when they exceed -67 dB (a value I determined experimentally), and then dumping the output to a file. Without the Head block, my file size exceeded 4 GB in just 10–15 seconds, which is obviously too much . I found that using the Head block helps manage the file size, but I’m unsure if it’s handling my high sample rate properly, given that I’ve set it to only record 10k samples. Could someone offer advice on whether this is an efficient approach at such a high sample rate, and if the Head block is appropriate in this context?
